# Unable to establish multiple foreign keys on mysql, specifically tested on mariaDB and w3schools online mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I was about to create two tables (1st table: fooditem_tbl & 2nd table: orderitem_tbl). I was planning to create 2 foreign keys (ITEM_NAME,UNIT_PRICE) on the 2nd table. I wasn't able to run the query of the 2nd table(orderitem_tbl), due to an error which is near at "INDEX". I kept looking at my query, and I still don't know what's the cause of the error.

## My first table , this one works

```
CREATE TABLE FOODITEM_TBL
(ITEM_ID         INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
ITEM_NAME        VARCHAR(50)  UNIQUE,
UNIT_PRICE       DOUBLE UNSIGNED,
ITEM_QUANTITY    INT UNSIGNED,
IN_STOCK         BOOLEAN,
PRIMARY KEY (ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, UNIT_PRICE));
```

## The 2nd table, which is below fails to create

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERITEM_TBL(
ORDER_ID         INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
ITEM_NAME        VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
UNIT_PRICE       DOUBLE UNSIGNED,
ITEM_QUANTITY    INT UNSIGNED,
CUSTOMER_NAME    VARCHAR(50),
ADDRESS          VARCHAR(50),
CONTACT_NUMBER   VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID),
INDEX (ITEM_NAME,UNIT_PRICE),
FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_NAME,UNIT_PRICE) REFERENCES 
  FOODITEM_TBL(ITEM_NAME,UNIT_PRICE)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

<strike>P.S Please help</strike>

Q: What is causing the error? How can I fix it?

Comment: This is rather a design problem. Usually you don't want `UNIT_PRICE` to be part of the FK. It should be possible to change the UNIT_PRICE in FOODITEM_TBL without affecting existing orders. Also the PK in FOODITEM_TBL makes little sense.

Comment: Does it really take 3 columns to uniquely identify a row in fooditem_tbl? Seems like item_id would suffice. Also, why store item_name in orderitem_tbl when it is already stored in fooditem_tbl?

Comment: Declare the tables in the "right" order or apply the FKs after creating the tables.  Check all the rules about what can and cannot be a FK.

Comment: Four of the columns are identical in the two tables?  Redunancy is _usually_ bad schema design.

Comment: Indexes are useful for performance; FKs are useful for integrity checks.

Answer (score 0):

For InnoDB, there must be an index on the target table, on the target column(s). Datatypes of the referencing foreign key column(s) must match the datatypes of the target column(s).

Before creating the foreign key constraint, make sure a suitable index exists on the target table, e.g.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `FOODITEM_TBL_UX3` ON `FOODITEM_TBL` (`ITEM_NAME`, `UNIT_PRICE`) ;
```

Given that `ITEM_NAME` is unique in the target table, we know that the combination of `ITEM_NAME` and `UNIT_PRICE` will also be unique. I'm not sure why we wouldn't just define a foreign key constraint on just `ITEM_NAME`, but that doesn't really address the question that was asked.

---

Personally, I would avoid floating point datatypes (e.g. `DOUBLE`) for columns involved in foreign key constraints.